# Change stylesheet based on Javascript if else statement

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

I'm making a page with lots of iframes on it, the websites in the iframes have ads in them and to make the page more viewable to people with adblock, I need to display different stylesheets.
Basically what I want to do is.. if adblock (display this stylesheet) else (display this stylesheet).

I have the code working to detect if adblock is present, but when I try to do the if else statement..the whole page is blank. Here's the code:

```
<script>
(function(){
    if($("#fakead").css('display')=="none")
    {
        document.write("<link href='css/adblock.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>")
    }
    else
    { 
        document.write("<link href='css/noadblock.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>")
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm extremely new to Javascript so my apologies if the code is terrible.

Thanks for any help

Comment: A simple reminder: when using document.write(), you are basically writing to the webpage. So there's a lesson for the day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `document.write` method. As I see you use jQuery, so in jQuery you can do like this:

```
$( function() {
    if($("#fakead").css('display')=="none") {
        $("<link href='css/adblock.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>").appendTo( 'head' );
    } else { 
        $("<link href='css/noadblock.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>").appendTo( 'head' )
    }
});
```

Please note: link element should be placed in `<head>` section. [Read more](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3) in w3c.

Comment: You are a wonderful person.  Thank you very much!  I'll select your answer as the correct one as soon as the 10 minutes have passed.

Comment: This answer is fine as it was first and shows you how to do it with jQuery, but for the sake of maintenance i'd take @Mikes code and refactor it into a generic function like function addStyle(path) { ... }

Comment: I've actually started to have a problem with the code.  At first it worked perfectly then all of a sudden it started to default to "noadblock.css" regardless of whether adblock was installed or not.

Comment: I honestly don't know, I slapped the code in there as is and it was fine until it wasn't.

Comment: @Kerblooy are there any JS errors in the console? Maybe you have a link to check?

Comment: I don't see any errors, here's the link to the page: http://www.criticalstrikesolutions.com/goreavote/lazytest.html

Comment: @Kerblooy yes, you need to run your script after DOM is loaded. See my updated code

Answer (score 4):

Pure JS option:

```
var el = document.createElement("link");
el.type = "text/css";
el.rel = "stylesheet";
el.href = "style.css";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(el);
```